# facebook fb.ui dialog opens too low

Tags: facebook, fb.ui

I'm having a problem and I can't find any resources to handle it, maybe someone here will have a clue...

I have a facebook app where I use fb.ui dialogs. The problem is that they open too low, and I need to scroll down in order to click accept/cancel.

The only resource I found told me to make sure that the  `<div id="fb-root"></div>` is right under the `<body>` tag, and this is the case with my app...

Any idea someone?
Thanks,
Yanipan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, eventually I used CSS directly on `#fb-root .dialog` which allowed me to apply the absolute position the way I wanted it, quite simple actually...

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div id="fb-root></div>` need to go higher up in your html. preferably as the first tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that, it just wasn't clear because the tags in the original message were stripped :)

Comment: Make sure you have just one <div id="fb-root"></div>
By accident i have added one more #fb-root to a page and it was overwriting the first one.